# View Dashboards based on user or profile

Tags: dashboard, dynamic, reports-folder

I want to create a dashboard and assign it to a user "XYZ" and restrict the user from viewing all the data.How can this be achieved?

[image]

Comment: what do you mean by restrict all the data?

Comment: Hi Tushar..Kindly see the attached pic.I want to remove the highlighted section from the dashboard for a specific profile.